# MobileVLCKit Http Stream Video play avi files without jitter, lag, grey screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, vlc

I am using MobileVLCKit for playing Http stream avi files. The Stream is ok when video filesize is small. Stream faces grey screen, jitter, lag when video file is large. Can anyone tell me how to solve this ? The log says -

[0000000154e74628] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 2193 ms)
[0000000154e74628] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0000000154e74628] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (jitter of 24516 ms ignored)

Pls forgive my writing as i am not used to write.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: Actually MobileVLCKit was conflicting with some libraries with FFMPEG. New updated build solved the issue.If you are also facing the same you may ask in their forum - [link](https://forum.videolan.org/viewforum.php?f=36&sid=30dfb363fb847c811154bce79298fedd). Hope that helps @Utsav Dusad